# Retrieve mp3 from mySQL and force download instead of playback in browser

Tags: php, http, download, mp3

I have a site with audio files in a mySQL database, all of which are available for playback. That works fine by using the headers:

```
header("Content-length:". $audioLength);
header("Content-type: ". $audioMime );


echo $audio;
```

Where the $audioLength and $audioMime are stored with the file in the database and $audio is the actual data.

I now want to add download links for some of the larger files so it would be very obvious to users who don't know how to download an mp3 from a page that they are welcome to do so and put the music on their devices and share them any other way they like. My PHP is the same except I replaced the headers with:

```
header("Content-type: attachment/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);

echo $audio;
```

This still causes Safari and Firefox to play the audio, just in a new window. How do I force a download dialog box? I assume most other browsers out there would play the file as well, so I haven't tested those yet...

M

OK - I'm a blasting idiot!!! I created the PHP file that would download instead of play back from the file that plays back. And I FORGOT TO CHANGE THE REFERENCE TO THE NEW PHP FILE IN THE URL to the files I was retrieving. Brilliant. I had it the first try, it just wasn't working because I was calling the wrong FILE.

So, for any people out there with this question - this is what works:

```
header('Content-Type: '.$audioMime);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);

echo $audio;
```

Ta-da!

Go ahead, laugh at me and give me the idiot of the day badge. I deserve it.

M

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `header("Content-type: attachment/octet-stream");`, try using `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`.

You also might want to add the following header:

`header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");`

Comment: So, now it looks like this:

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileName);
    header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    echo $audio;
and still plays instead of downloading...

Comment: cache-control should have no effect at all (when testing things like this of course you should clear the cache before retrying)

Answer (score 0):

1) don't send a different content-type.

2) the unquoted syntax only works if a filename is a token (as defined in MIME), for instance, it can't contain spaces.

In doubt, install LiveHTTPHeaders in Firefox and post what you see on the wire.

Comment: OK - I changed the content type back. I posted a response to your answer in the main body of the questions because there are not enough chars allowed here...

Comment: You can add more characters by quoting the filename. You can add even more by using the encoding defined in RFC 2231 and 5987 (but this isn't supported in IE/Safari/Chrome).